# Socket.io set session variable at disconnect

Tags: javascript, session, events, socket.io, disconnect

I created a socket.io server. When a client leaves a room I want to set the `socket.handshake.session.canal` to the "0" value. But it is not working.

I work with the express shared session stored on a Redis server. Any idea to solve this issue?

```
socket.on("disconnect", function() {
if (people[socket.id] != undefined)
{
    if (people[socket.id].inroom != false)
    {
        var room = rooms[people[socket.id].inroom];
        if (room)
        {
            if (_.contains((room.people), socket.id))
            {
                var personIndex = room.people.indexOf(socket.id);
                room.people.splice(personIndex, 1);
                room.peoples = room.peoples-1;
                socket.leave(room.id);
                if (socket.handshake.session.isLogged == true)
                {
                    io.to(room.id).emit('userleft', socket.handshake.session.pseudo);
                }
                socket.handshake.session.canal = 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            socket.leave(room.id);
            socket.handshake.session.canal = 0;
        }
    }
    delete people[socket.id];
    delete sockets[socket];
}
```

Comment: "But it is not working." --- what does this mean?

Comment: @zerkms After the disconnect event, the `socket.handshake.session.canal` is not to "0" value.. (Checked by emit a custom event to client)

Comment: "Checked by emit a custom event to client" --- are you sure it happened *after*?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, in this case, the user leaving the room is redirected back on the home page that  connect to socket.io that sending the variable directly

Comment: "is redirected back on the home page" --- how? Using the complete page reload?

Comment: @zerkms Yes a complete page reload using a html href attribute.

Comment: So, if a page completely reloads - how would you get the same socket instance?

Comment: @zerkms sharedsession with express and socket.io take sid cookie to read and write session content to a redis server, so the socket instance doesn't have importance here. All of my code works except this.

Comment: @zerkms sooo any idea to solve this issue ?

Comment: My current and the only idea - is that you're not getting the session. To confirm/discard it you need to take debugger and check that the value was stored into the session storage and that after the page reload the same session was (or was not) restored.

Comment: @zerkms I've already did that, in the disconnect event, the session object in redis is not saved, any other event save the session variable..

Comment: "is not saved" -- so take debugger and check why

Comment: How can I find a debugger to check that please ? (A node.js debugger ? on linux pls)

Comment: Yes, just nodejs debugger.

Comment: @zerkms the node.js debugger don't say anything on my problem.

Comment: "don't say anything" --- it makes no sense. If you have gone through the whole process of storing/loading the session - you must have an answer now. So, did it store the session? Did it load it?

Comment: Yes it load because there is a condition in the code with session variable, at the end of the disconnect event, the session variable "canal" is "0" but after reload, back to "1"

Comment: So, did it store the session? If it loads the session - what is *raw data* in the session? Does it have your data? "but after reload, back to "1" " --- take debugger and tell why it happens.

Comment: @zerkms raw data contain my session in JSON format, debugger didn't say anything, when I console.log(socket.handshake.session) at the end of disconnect event, i see canal to 0 but when I reload the page to go on the homepage, canal is 1

Comment: So, was the correct data *actually persisted* in a session storage? (I'm not sure how long I'm gonna ask this very question).

Comment: @zerkms no it's not persist in session storage, in "live" in the disconnect event okay, but not in storage, and I think it's only with disconnect event but with another event (emit) it's working...

Comment: @zerkms and on redis storage the data who persist is the data canal = 1 and not canal = 0 who i'm trying to set on disconnect event.

Comment: So, why is not it persisted in the storage?

Comment: @zerkms I don't know, it's why I'm here asking a solution

Comment: Take a debugger and find out why it does not save it.

Comment: @zerkms As I say just earlier, the debugger didn't say anything.

Comment: It should not "say anything" - you should take it and answer "why it does not save it" question.